# Code compiles with scalac but not in REPL

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

I have some code, say in `Foo.scala` that compiles readily with `scalac`, 
but I get a blizzard of errors when I boot up the REPL and say `:load Foo.scala`. 
I imagine this is standard and documented but can't seem to find any relevant 
information about it.

The file looks like this:

```
abstract class BST[A](implicit cmp: A => Ordered[A]) {
  def fold[B](f: (B, A) => B, acc: B): B = {
    this match {
      case Leaf()        => acc
    }                 
  } 
} 

case class Leaf[A]()(implicit cmp: A => Ordered[A]) extends BST[A]
```

And I get errors like so:

```
scala> :load BST3.scala
Loading BST3.scala...
<console>:10: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : Leaf[A(in class Leaf)]
 required: BST[A(in class BST)]
             case Leaf()        => acc
                  ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `:load` tries to interpret the file block-by-block.  Since your blocks are mutually-dependent, this is a problem.

Try using "paste mode" to paste multiple blocks into the REPL for Scala to compile together:

```
scala> :paste

// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

abstract class BST[A](implicit cmp: A => Ordered[A]) {
  def fold[B](f: (B, A) => B, acc: B): B = {
    this match {
      case Leaf()        => acc
    }                 
  } 
} 

case class Leaf[A]()(implicit cmp: A => Ordered[A]) extends BST[A]

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class BST
defined class Leaf
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip re: paste mode!