# Pasting into REPL with :paste

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

Looking at this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343516/code-compiles-with-scalac-but-not-in-repl), I tried to paste the following code into Putty and Windows command line.

```
def size(root: Leaf, left: Branch, right: Branch) : Int = {
   def go(branch: Branch, acc: Int) : Int = branch match {
       case Nil => acc
       case branch.left != Nil && branch.right != Nil => go(branch.left, acc) + 
                                                          go(branch.right, acc)
       case branch.left != Nil => go(branch.left, acc)
       case branch.right != Nil => go(branch.right, acc)
       case _ => 0
   }
  root match {
    case Nil => go(left, 0) + go(right, 0)
    case _ => 1 + go(left, 0) + go(right, 0)
  }
}
```

However, even though I'm simply pasting into Putty and Windows 7 command line, the following gets output:

> scala> :paste // Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)
>
> def size(root: Leaf, left: Branch, right: Branch) : Int = {    def
>   go(branch: Branch, acc: Int) : Int = branch match {
>          case Nil => acc
>
> =:=                          AnyRef                       ArrowAssoc                   Class ClassManifest                Downloads
>   DummyImplicit                Ensuring Function
>   Manifest                     Map                          NoManifest
>   OptManifest                  Pair                         Set
>   String Triple                       *root*
>   arrayToCharSequence          asInstanceOf assert
>   assume                       augmentString                bin ch
>   classManifest                classOf                      com

It's not compiling due to, I believe, this unexpected output behavior when I try to paste.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether there are TAB characters in there. sbt triggers code completion when you press TAB. It does it also in paste mode. So it might have tried to complete your statement and completed it wrong.

Comment: Good one. Haven't tried it, but there's tabs in what he pasted.  `00000090  69 6c 20 3d 3e 20 61 63  63 0a 20 20 20 20 09 20  |il => acc.    . |`