# Undesired variable dump in Scala REPL

Tags: scala, paste, dump, read-eval-print-loop

When using the Scala REPL, I sometimes get an undesired dump of all the variables.  I believe this mostly happens (always happens) when in :paste mode.

This is somewhat annoying if I later want to scroll back in my window to see what I did before since the history is limited in Windows command windows.

To reproduce, I do the following steps.

First, I start scala REPL inside a Windows 8.1 (alas, it was on my new machine) command window.

Then I enter paste mode by typing :paste.

Thirdly, I paste in the following simple Scala code.

```
// Find the minimum and maximum of an array using foldLeft 
{
val nums = Array[Int](1, 4, 7, 2, 9, 3, -2, 5, 11, 4, 6)
def minmax( nums : Array[Int] ) : (Int, Int) = {
    nums.foldLeft((nums(0),nums(0))) (
      (n, m) => { 
        (n._1 min m, n._2 max m) 
      }    
    )
}
minmax( nums )
}
```

Finally (although the problem is visible now), I press ctrl-D to exit paste mode.

After doing the paste in step 3, and prior to step 4, the following gets dumped to the screen:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)
{
  val nums = Array[Int](1, 4, 7, 2, 9, 3, -2, 5, 11, 4, 6)
  def minmax( nums : Array[Int] ) : (Int, Int) = {
    nums.foldLeft((nums(0),nums(0))) (
      (n, m) => {

$intp                 assume                       println
???                   augmentString                quicktime
ArrayCharSequence     classManifest                readBoolean
ArrowAssoc            classOf                      readByte
... multiple rows of symbols deleted for brevity ...
arrayToCharSequence   org                          unwrapString
asInstanceOf          print
assert                printf
    (n._1 min m, n._2 max m)
      }
    )
  }
  minmax( nums )
}
```

Any ideas on what triggers this dump and what I might do to avoid it in the future?  There does not seem to be any rhyme or reason to it that I can spot.

Thanks
TJ

Comment: I can't replicate this copy/pasting your snippet in gnome term, but this looks like the output you get hitting `<Tab>` (for code completion).
There appears to be a whitespace after the `{` where you get the code dump, could you try without it ?

Comment: Version? Scala 2.11 updates Jline. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222272/pasting-into-repl-with-paste and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097896/temporarily-disable-tab-completion-in-scala-repl